# Pearson Correlation and Linear Combination

Tags: correlation

$\newcommand{\Cov}{\operatorname{Cov}}$
I seek to find the Pearson correlation between two linear combinations and express it as a linear combination

In particular, let $x,y,w,z$ be vectors $\in \mathbb{R^n}$ and $a,b,c,d$ constants. Find $A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4$ such that $\rho(ax + cw, by + dz) = A_1 \rho(x,y) + A_2 \rho(w,y) + A_3 \rho(x,z) + A_4\rho(w,z)$

I have tried the following

\begin{align*}
\rho(ax + cw, by+dz) 
&= \frac{\Cov(ax + cw, by+dz)}{\sqrt{V(ax + cw)}\sqrt{V(by+dz)}}\\
&= \frac{ab \Cov(x,y) + ad \Cov(x,z) + cb \Cov(w,y) + cd \Cov(w,z)}{\sqrt{a^2V(x) + c^2V(w) + 2ac\Cov(x,w)}\sqrt{b^2V(y) + d^2V(z) + 2bd\Cov(x,w)}}.
\end{align*}

How can I arrange the previous expression in order to get the desired result?

Comment: Shall we presume you will allow the $A_i$ to depend on $a,b,c,d$ but not on anything else, so that this should be a universal statement for *all* such vectors?

Comment: @whuber: Is that even possible? I'm not sure I see how to do it without involving correlations and variances of the variables.

Comment: The $A_i$ can involve the variances of the variables. I believe there is a lot of algebra in between though I cant grasp how to make it easier.

Comment: @Adrian No, it's not possible--but anything else would just be an algebraic triviality and of no statistical interest.

Comment: I thought the same, that is why I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Cov}{\operatorname{Cov}}$
Let $u_1=ax+cw$ and $u_2=by+dz$. Then we have
\begin{align*}
\rho(u_1,u_2)
&=\frac{\Cov(u_1,u_2)}{\sqrt{V(u_1)}\sqrt{V(u_2)}}.
\end{align*}
Let $C=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{V(u_1)}\sqrt{V(u_2)}},$ so that we have
\begin{align*}
\rho(u_1,u_2)
&=C\left[ab\Cov(x,y)+ad\Cov(x,z)+bc\Cov(w,y)+cd\Cov(w,z)\right]\\
&=C\big[ab\sqrt{V(x)}\sqrt{V(y)}\,\rho(x,y)+ad\sqrt{V(x)}\sqrt{V(z)}\,\rho(x,z)\\
&\qquad+bc\sqrt{V(w)}\sqrt{V(y)}\,\rho(w,y)+cd\sqrt{V(w)}\sqrt{V(z)}\,\rho(w,z)\big],
\end{align*}
so that
\begin{align*}
A_1&=\frac{ab\sqrt{V(x)}\sqrt{V(y)}}{\sqrt{V(ax+cw)}\sqrt{V(by+dz)}}\\
A_2&=\frac{bc\sqrt{V(w)}\sqrt{V(y)}}{\sqrt{V(ax+cw)}\sqrt{V(by+dz)}}\\
A_3&=\frac{ad\sqrt{V(x)}\sqrt{V(z)}}{\sqrt{V(ax+cw)}\sqrt{V(by+dz)}}\\
A_4&=\frac{cd\sqrt{V(w)}\sqrt{V(z)}}{\sqrt{V(ax+cw)}\sqrt{V(by+dz)}}.
\end{align*}